# Удалить строки в файлах определенной папки рекурсивно ранее определенной даты SED, AWK

Tags: bash, sed, awk

подскажите как с помощью sed, awk удалить все что старше 7 денй рекурсивно во всех файлах , во всех папках /home/*/ *.log в файлах.
Формат файла такой:

```
2018-12-23 23:34:43.358 7 INFO 
2019-06-12 12:33:43.358 7 INFO 
2020-05-12 11:23:43.358 7 INFO 
2020-09-23 10:34:43.358 7 INFO
```

Comment: Исправьте свой вопрос. Заголовок не соответствует содержанию, тэги тоже.

Answer (score 2):

**Важно!**
Данный ответ как таковым **решением не является** и мне кажется вряд ли будет решение которое подойдет путем `sed` или `awk`.
Во время выполнения сценария, из логов будут удалены все строки не начинающиеся с даты формата **%Y-%m-%d**, т.е. если будет строка за сегодня, потом строка без указания даты и опять строка за сегодня, то строка без даты все равно будет удалена.
Так же большой диапазон дат может вызвать ошибку при выполнении.

```bsh
#Переменная для указания промежутка времени, текущий день +1, т.е. если указано 6, то получаем с сегодняшним днем 7 дней
todate=6
#Так как переменная дописываемая, лучше ее очищать
unset datestr
#Цикл для формирования строки с датами, для дальнейшего использования в команде sed
for ((i=-$todate; i<=0; i++)); do
    if [ $i -eq 0 ]; then
        datestr+=`date -d "$i day" +'^%Y-%m-%d'`
    else
        datestr+=`date -d "$i day" +'^%Y-%m-%d\|'`
    fi
done
#Обрабатываем все файлы подходящие под маску, удаляя из них все кроме строк где в начале будут строки из диапазона дат созданных в цикле
sed /"$datestr"/\!d /home/*/*.log
```

В sed убран параметр `-i`, который перезаписует файл, перед его добавлением лучше убедится, что вывод команды корректен и не возникает ошибко, параметр устанавливается сразу после вызова `sed -i ...`

---

Потребность в удалении логов, а так же оптимизации хранения и не только, можно удовлетворить с помощью того же `logrotate`, более подробно можно прочитать в интернете или выполнить команду `man logrotate` в терминале.

Comment: +1 за `logrotate` - IMO другие решения - это разновидности костылей...